# What is the best way to represent this categorical vs float data graphically?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, scikit-learn

I want to represent a categorical variable (Student Achievement Rating) versus a float variable (Percent White). I've tried using a scatter plot like so but it doesn't really work and present the data nicely.

Ideally I am then going to compare Student Achievement Score versus Percent White/Black/Hispanic to see if there is a difference in each plot.

My data is in a dataframe like so:
[image]

My current plot looks like this:

[image]

Comment: What about a boxplot? https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/pyplots/boxplot_demo_pyplot.html#sphx-glr-gallery-pyplots-boxplot-demo-pyplot-py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there are many options for that case, but I'd suggest two:

- You can plot a bar chart with categories and some grouped statistic like mean/median/or with a custom statistic(s).
- Besides that I'd suggest you to draw histogram by groups.

The former is pretty straightforward, so I can suggest a code snippet for the latter.

You can use plotly express to plot the latter.

```
import plotly_express as px

fig = px.histogram(data, 'Percent White', color = 'Student Achievement Rating')
fig.update_layout(barmode = 'overlay')
fig.update_traces(opacity = 0.6) # reducing the opacity to see the overlayed bars. 
fig.show()
```

You can check the documentation [here](https://plot.ly/python/plotly-express/). Feel free to play around with the methods and parameters as you need.